# How do I make a sql request in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sum

### How do I make a sql request in codeigniter

Codeigniter request

```
  $this->db->select('visites.id, persons.fio, sum(services.cena)');
    $this->db->from('visites');
    $this->db->join('persons', 'visites.clients = persons.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('draft', 'draft.vis = visites.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('services', 'draft.ser = services.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->group_by(array("visites.id, persons.fio")); 

        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

## How to create correctly request?

Comment: what error displayed ?

Comment: u have created, what is the error?

Comment: I dont know how to get print on page 
`$list = $this->visit->get_datatables();
  $data = array();
  $no = $_POST['start'];
  foreach ($list as $visit) {
   $no++;
   $row = array();
   $row[] = $visit->id;
   $row[] = $visit->fio;
   $row[] = $visit->sum;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use
$this->db->select('visites.id, persons.fio, sum(services.cena)');
    $this->db->from('visites');
    $this->db->join('persons', 'visites.clients = persons.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('draft', 'draft.vis = visites.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('services', 'draft.ser = services.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->group_by(array("visites.id, persons.fio")); 



 if($_POST['length'] >= 0)
{
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
}
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean "Passing data to view" ?

Controller

```
$data['list'] = $this->your_model->fn();
$this->load->view("your_view",$data);
```

View

```
<?php print_r($list); ?>
```